# CS6 Fluid Grids and High Density Displays

Tags: grid, dreamweaver, media-queries, fluid

I have a question regarding Dreamweaver CS6's implementation of responsive design. If i were to use the default media query settings (phone=480px wide, tablet=768px wide, and desktop=1232px wide), what will happen when viewing the site on a retina ipad?

The retina ipad has a width of 1536px, but it's a tablet. Will the site built with CS6's Fluid Grid show up using desktop site media query?

My question also applies to the Droid DNA. It has a width of 1080px, but it's a phone. Will the site built with CS6's Fluid Grid show up as a tablet site on the Droid DNA?

Does Dreamweaver take all of this into account? I know that there is a way to use pixel ratios as parts of a media queries, but will that be needed for a site made with CS6's fluid grid layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that pixel is not an absolute unit. It's relative like percent, em, rem...
So the retina display has a higher dpi (dots per inch) value but should be recognized as tablet since Apple knows this too.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. That's what I was hoping for.

Comment: @NickPassaro I am not an iPad owner, so I can't provide more detailed information about it... Remember to choose an answer...